# Applying a file as a texture in Maya python

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to take a file texture that I added previously in my code and add it to a selected mesh in maya. I'm pretty new to python and scripting in general and I've been struggling with this for a couple days now, so my code is probably a mess.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from os import listdir

class TextureImport():
    def __init__(self):
        if cmds.window(TextureImport, q=True, exists=True):
            cmds.deleteUI(TextureImport)
        GUI=cmds.window(title="Texture Import Tool", widthHeight=(250,160), s=True, tlb=True)
        cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=1, columnAlign=(1, 'center'), columnAttach=(1, 'both', 0), cw=(1,250))
        cmds.button(label="Select Directory", command=self.select_dir)
        cmds.separator(style='in', h=20)
        cmds.optionMenu('optionMenu', label="File List")
        cmds.button(label="Clear List", command=self.clear_list)
        cmds.separator(style='in', h=20)
        cmds.text('Select your object, then:', h=25)
        cmds.button(label="Apply Texture", command=self.apply_texture)
        cmds.setParent('..')
        cmds.showWindow()

    def select_dir(self, *args):
        basicFilter = "Image Files (*.jpg *.jpeg *.tga *.png *.tiff *.bmp *.psd)"
        self.myDir = cmds.fileDialog2 (fileFilter=basicFilter, dialogStyle=2, fm=3)
        myFiles = listdir(self.myDir[0])

        for items in myFiles:
            fileEndings = ('.psd','.PSD','.jpg','JPG','.jpeg','.JPEG','.tga','.TGA','.png','.PNG','.tiff','.TIFF','.bmp','.BMP')
            if items.endswith(fileEndings):
                cmds.menuItem(items)
            else:
                cmds.warning(items + 'This is not a valid image type, you fool.')
        print myFiles

    def clear_list(self, *args):
        fileList = cmds.optionMenu('optionMenu', q=True, itemListLong=True)
        if fileList:
            cmds.deleteUI(fileList)

    def apply_texture(self, *args):
        object = cmds.ls(sl=True)
        selectedMenuItem = cmds.optionMenu('optionMenu', q=True, value=True)
        cmds.sets(name='imageMaterialGroup', renderable=True, empty=True)
        shaderNode = cmds.shadingNode('phong', name='shaderNode', asShader=True)
        fileNode = cmds.shadingNode('file', name='fileTexture', asTexture=True)
        cmds.setAttr('fileTexture'+'.fileTextureName', self.myDir[0]+'/'+selectedMenuItem, type="string")
        shadingGroup = cmds.sets(name='textureMaterialGroup', renderable=True, empty=True)
        cmds.connectAttr('shaderNode'+'.outColor','textureMaterialGroup'+'.surfaceShader')
        cmds.connectAttr('fileTexture'+'.outColor','shaderNode'+'.color')
        cmds.surfaceShaderList('shaderNode', add='imageMaterialGroup')
        cmds.sets(object, e=True, forceElement='imageMaterialGroup')
TextureImport()
```

The problem comes in at the end when I try to use the last button. It throws the error:

Error: 'textureMaterialGroup.surfaceShader' already has an incoming connection from 'lambert1.outColor'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 52, in apply_texture
RuntimeError: 'textureMaterialGroup.surfaceShader' already has an incoming connection from 'lambert1.outColor'.

I'm not sure what lambert has to do with it, as it doesn't factor into my code at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have a connection there, so if you want to force it to connect, you need to add the `force` argument like this:

```
cmds.connectAttr('shaderNode'+'.outColor','textureMaterialGroup'+'.surfaceShader', force=True)
cmds.connectAttr('fileTexture'+'.outColor','shaderNode'+'.color', force=True)
```

From the [connectAttr docs](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2012/en_us/CommandsPython/connectAttr.html), `force`:

> Forces the connection. If the destination is already connected, the
>   old connection is broken and the new one made.